# Get GKE workload status

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I aim to get the status of GKE workloads as shown in the GCP UI in either stackriver logging or using a gcloud command.

Also, I don't want to use the kubectl cli. 
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-workloads-overview#inspecting_live_configurations
as mentioned here.

Comment: Hello. Could you please tell what exactly are you trying to achieve? Do I understand correctly that you want to get a usage of kubernetes cluster without using any variation of `kubectl` command? Have you checked the `GCP->Monitoring->Dashboard(of your GKE cluster)`?

Comment: logging won't have this and gcloud won't work either, but you might be able to pull the status using the stackdriver monitoring API